# Optimize LEFT JOINS ORDER BY on multiple varchar columns

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, left-join

I tried to optimize a MySQL query which sort multiple varchar columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers ON customers.id = tickets.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN locations ON locations.id = tickets.location_id
ORDER BY customers.name, locations.name;
```

The ORDER BY statement seems to cost lot of time(~100ms) for a small database of ~6000 tickets, ~40 customers and ~400 locations.

I already reduced the length of varchar columns, which had significantly speed up the query(2x faster).

Do you have any solutions to optimize the query execution time?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have indexes on customer.name and locations.name? If not, add them and check how this will speed up your query

Answer (score 2):

You should have indexes on the `customers.name` and `locations.name` columns.

Additionally, ensure that `customers.id`, `tickets.customer_id`, `locations.id`, and `tickets.location_id` are all indexed.

Comment: The ids are indexed and the execution time is the same after "CREATE INDEX name ON customers(name)" and "CREATE INDEX name ON locations(name)". Strange?

Comment: "ORDER BY customers.name, locations.name" is not in same table,it should not be avoid filesort and temporary table,is't it?